# How to stop rotation of icons in the v-autocomplete component?

Tags: vue-component

I am trying to use v-autocomplete for a search box. Since its a search box, I am changing the triangle to a search icon using [append-icon="search"]. Now the problem is the search icon rotates 180 and flips upside down. What is the solution to stop that from happening?

```
<v-autocomplete
   label="Search the collection"
   append-icon="search"
   :items ="components"
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Vuetify applies a 180 degree rotation to appended icons of active `v-select` components

```
<style>
  .v-select.v-select--is-menu-active .v-input__icon--append .v-icon {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
</style>
```

I was appending a search icon to my autocomplete component, but it would always turn upside-down when the menu opened. I solved it by simply overriding the above:

```
<style>
  .v-autocomplete.v-select--is-menu-active .v-input__icon--append .v-icon {
    transform: none;
  }
</style>
```

Of course, you might not want to override this for all selects. I would recommended you to be as specific as possible when overriding default styles.

Comment: Make sure that your `<style>` tag is **NOT** scoped.

Answer (score 1):

Well after some search the only solution i came up with is to remove the css class responsible for the rotation using javascript like this:

```
var transformClass = document.querySelector(".v-input__icon--append");
transformClass.classList.remove("v-input__icon--append");
```

here is an [example](https://codepen.io/crowlinf3ar/pen/YzKYJjo)

Answer (score 1):

Use the existing notranslate class to force transform to none as follow:

```
<style>
.notranslate {
  transform: none!important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Vuetify variable](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#select-active-icon-flip), `$select-active-icon-flip` on the `<v-select>` component. Just put

```
$select-active-icon-flip: false;
```

in your variables overrides.

Be warned that this will disable the flip for all selects and autocompletes. If you want it only for autocompletes then you might need to use one of the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is via inspect element and I manually check one by one what's the selector that's causing the rotation.

```
 .v-autocomplete :deep(.v-field__append-inner > .v-icon) {
  transform: none !important;
}
```